# Passing correct properties to popup notification

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, antd

I want to show a notification with the upload status. I took over a project in React & ASP.NET and I am relatively new to this. The question is quite simple, yet I am struggling to solve it: **How do I display a popup notification showing which files have been successfully been uploaded and which not?**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Form, Select, Button, Upload, message, notification} from 'antd';
import * as Actions from "../actions";

const FormItem = Form.Item;

class UploadFileForm extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        message.config({ top: 0 });
        message.loading('Importing in progress...', 3);
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.uploadFile(this.props.form.getFieldsValue());
          notification["info"]({
          message: 'Files successfully uploaded',
          description: '', // <-- this line has to be modified
          duration: 10
        });
    }
    render() {
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <FormItem label="File" >
                    {getFieldDecorator('upload', {
                        valuePropName: 'fileList',
                        getValueFromEvent: (e) => e.fileList.slice(-1)
                    })(
                        <Upload name="importFile" action={' '} multiple={false}>
                            <Button> Upload </Button>
                        </Upload>
                        )}
                </FormItem>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Import</Button>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}
export default Form.create()(UploadFileForm);
```

More specifically: How do I have to modify the line `description: '',` to show me a list of all uploaded files and their status as pure text, e.g. `File(s) '1.txt', '2.txt', and '3.txt' have been successfully uploaded. File(s) '4.txt' failed.`?

The project documentation says that we are using Redux-Saga, but I am not so maybe that makes the story easier.

Comment: You need to add state to the app, maybe an array and push the file name to the state here `(e) => e.fileList.slice(-1)`. You'll be able to use that to convert to string and pass it to the description

Comment: @paruchuri-p I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: It isn't possible to answer this fully without seeing the other parts of the app, unfortunately. In general terms, your `uploadFile` prop looks like it triggers the upload. This would normally dispatch a redux action which would trigger a saga to handle the upload. The results of the upload would then be passed in to your store, and you would pass these results to your notification component via a prop, either from a parent or the `connect` function.

Comment: @WillJenkins: Which other part of the code do you need? I found some services, but I am not sure which ones I should post. I did try to search for references with Visual Studio Professional, but that did not help too much. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Your uploadFile action is (I guess) a promise so you should update notification once that promise is resolved. Your server however should return list of success/failure files which you could then use to generate required text.

Comment: How much do you know about React, props, redux and sagas? The parent component would be useful place to start

Comment: @WillJenkins: I am quite new to the topics you mentioned, but thanks to some Youtube Tutorials I have a basic understanding of the concepts, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `this.props.uploadFile` method is a `promise` so considering that you should show notification once that `promise` is resolved

```
this.props.uploadFile(this.props.form.getFieldsValue()).then(result => {
    // since your client doesn't know which ones are success/failed, server should return
    // this information when request is finished

   const { successUploads, failUploads } = result;

    notification["info"]({
        message: 'Files successfully uploaded',
        description: `File(s) ${successUploads.join(', ')} have been successfully uploaded. File(s) ${failUploads.join(', ')} failed.`
        duration: 10
     });
});
```

If you can't control whats returned from the server then you'd need to track uploads on client side, but that would mean having multiple uploads (requests) to the server and your upload method would look something like this:

```
async function uploadFiles(files) {
    // I've called your server upload uploadService.send(), but replace this with your method
    const results = await Promise.all(
        files.map(file => uploadService.send(file))
             .map(p => p.catch(e => e)
    );

    let successUploads = [];
    let failUploads = [];
    results.forEach((result, idx) => {
        const file = files[idx];
        if (result instanceof Error) {
            failUploads.push(file);
        } else {
            successUploads.push(file);
        }
    });

    return {
        successUploads,
        failUploads
    }
}
```

Then you could call `uploadFiles` same way as shown in first snippet.